# Are modules == mixins in ruby?

Tags: ruby

I have read in many textbooks that

*In Ruby,a class can only be a subclass of one class. Mixins, however, allow classes without a common ancestor to share methods.*

In practice, whenever I need to implement multiple inheritance. I have use `Modules` & not mixins. for example:

```
Module name_goes_here
  def method_name_goes_here
    .....
  end
end
```

Then, I just include them in a class

```
class MySubClass < MySuperClass
  include module_name
end
```

now, I have referred to multiple ruby books each talking about mixins & then suddenly, all of they start talking about modules without making it clear what is the relation of mixins & modules.

so, Question is:
Are modules == mixins in ruby? if yes, then why. if no, then what's the difference?

PS: sorry, if its a silly question

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Mixins are a language concept that allows to inject some code into a class.

This is implemented in Ruby by the keyword `include` that takes a `Module` as a parameter.

So yes, in Ruby, mixins are implemented with modules. But modules have other uses than mixins.

For example, modules can also be used for namespacing your classes or encapsulating utility functions to keep from polluting the global namespace.

Comment: Apart from mixins, What are the "other uses" of modules in ruby?

Comment: @Gaurish They can be used for namespacing or encapsulating methods that don't belong in a class to keep from polluting the global namespace.

Comment: @AndrewMarshall Thanks, I added your contribution in the answer

Answer (score 5):

From [wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mixin)

> In object-oriented programming languages, a mixin is a class that provides a certain functionality to be inherited or just reused by a subclass, while not meant for instantiation (the generation of objects of that class).

So yes, modules in Ruby provide a way to reuse functionality without instantiating modules themselves. I'd say, "mixins in ruby are implemented with modules", but not "mixins are modules and vice versa".